# PaymentDetails is not successfully deserialized, returning a null object, because it seems it is expected to have IXmlDeserializable

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, ixmlserializable

```
[XmlRoot("Quote")]
public class Quote
{
    [XmlElement("Insurance")]
    public InsuranceDetails InsDetails { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Payment")]
    public PaymentDetails PayDetails { get; set; }
}

public class InsuranceDetails : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Details1")]
    public string Details1 { get; set; }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
            reader.ReadStartElement("Insurance");
               Details1 = reader.ReadElementString("Details1");
            reader.ReadEndElement();
    }
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        // do write suff
    }
}

public class PaymentDetails
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Details1")]
    public string Details1 { get; set; }
}
```

Given this example, using XmlSerializer to deserialize my string to QuoteObject, PaymentDetails is not successfully deserialized, returning a null object, because it seems it is expected to have IXmlDeserializable. It only works if PaymentDetails is parsed in first place. Is this some expected behavior from XmlSerializer?

```
using (TextReader read = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Quote));
    return (Quote)serializer.Deserialize(read);
}
```

Comment: Kinda depends on the code you are using to deserialize with, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: I tested using your class definitions and it is working fine. Can you post the XML string so that we can examine it for any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well these are the `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` I modified:

```
 public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
 {
    reader.MoveToContent();
    var empty=reader.IsEmptyElement;
    reader.ReadStartElement();
    if(!empty){
        Details1=reader.ReadElementString("Details1");
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }
}
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    var str=string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Details1)?"":Details1;            
    writer.WriteElementString("Details1",str);
}
```

Following are serialize and deserialize functions:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T t)
{
    var xmlser=new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));    
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();

    using(StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter()) {
        using(XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings)) {
            xmlser.Serialize(xmlWriter, t);
        }
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml) 
{
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml)) {
        return default(T);
    }

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

    using(StringReader textReader = new StringReader(xml)) {
        using(XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings)) {
            return (T) serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Serialization Test:

```
var q=new Quote();
q.PayDetails = new PaymentDetails{Details1="Payment Details 1"};
q.InsDetails=new InsuranceDetails{Details1="Insurance Details 1"};  

str = Serialize<Quote>(q);
```

Which gives (str):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Quote xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Payment>
        <Details1>Payment Details 1</Details1>
    </Payment>
    <Insurance>
        <Details1>Insurance Details 1</Details1>
    </Insurance>
</Quote>
```

Deserialization Test:

```
var dq=Deserialize<Quote>(str);

Console.WriteLine(dq.PaymentDetails.Detail1);//gives "Payment Details 1"
Console.WriteLine(dq.InsuranceDetails.Detail1);//gives "Insurance Details 1"
```

PS:- The Serialize code was copied from another SO answer verbatim. I learned how to serialize to string using `StringWriter`.

Comment: Many thanks... unfortunately the code was bad inheritance, ReadEndElement() was missing and the pointer was in the wrong position.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't have to implement `IXmlSerializable` in any of the classes. Second of all, you don't provide the content of the `xml` variable. It may contain a mistype/bug, if you created it manually.

I used the following code, to test your classes:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlDeSerialize
{
    [XmlRoot("Quote")]
    public class Quote
    {
        [XmlElement("Insurance")]
        public InsuranceDetails InsDetails { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Payment")]
        public PaymentDetails PayDetails { get; set; }
    }
    public class InsuranceDetails
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Details1")]
        public string Details1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class PaymentDetails
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Details1")]
        public string Details1 { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var qin = new Quote
            {
                InsDetails = new InsuranceDetails { Details1 = "insurance details text" },
                PayDetails = new PaymentDetails { Details1 = "payment details text" },
            };

            string xml;
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Quote));
                serializer.Serialize(stream, qin);
                stream.Position = 0;
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            Quote qout;
            using (TextReader read = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Quote));
                var obj = deserializer.Deserialize(read);
                qout = (Quote)obj;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("InsDetails.Details1='{0}'", qout.InsDetails.Details1);
            Console.WriteLine("PayDetails.Details1='{0}'", qout.PayDetails.Details1);
        }
    }
}
```

The value of `xml` after serialization:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Quote xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Insurance>
        <Details1>insurance details text</Details1>
    </Insurance>
    <Payment>
        <Details1>payment details text</Details1>
    </Payment>
</Quote>
```

The console output I received:

```xml
InsDetails.Details1='insurance details text'
PayDetails.Details1='payment details text'
```

Try the code yourself and see if it works for you. Clearly to me you don't provide valid XML  content for deserialization, or other part of your code you did not provide in your question is to blame.

Comment: U're right, IXmlSerializable is not needed in this specific case and the problem was caused by missing ReadEndElement() on IXmlSerializable ReadXml implementation. Thanks